# Regulator oxidizing NO to NO2

Tags: catalysis, gas-phase-chemistry

I have a regulator that is somehow oxidizing NO to NO2. Using a different regulator does not cause this same issue. I was wondering what could possible be contaminating the regulator that would facilitate this reaction (there are no leaks so far as I can tell meaning no O3 of HO2 should be getting in there) and what I could try to resolve this. So far, I have tried to flush it with ultrapure zero air and put the regulator under vacuum for 24 hrs. and neither of these fixed this issue. Probably a strange place to ask but I figured maybe someone has seen this issue before, I would hate to have to dispose of a rather expensive regulator!

Thank you!

Comment: What is a regulator ? How does it work ? Is it a catalyst ? How do you know that $\ce{NO}$ is not oxidized into $\ce{NO2}$ ?

Comment: Maurice - A regulator is a device attached to gas storage tanks that regulates pressure (and thus flow) from the high pressure tank to a relatively low pressure system. The regulator is installed to: 1: prevent over pressurization that would be caused by opening a gas tank; and 2: prevent backflow contamination into the tank. I have a tank of pure NO in zero nitrogen. Something (within the regulator) is catalyzing the oxidation reaction of NO to NO2, but I do not believe it is a gas phase species. I was wondering if anyone had seen a regulator contamination like this before.

Comment: Please be more precise ! What are you calling "gas storage tank" ? What do you mean with "high pressure tank" ? And what is a "relatively low pressure system" ? System ? Which system ? NO cannot be oxidized into NO2 without oxygen. Where is the oxygen coming from ? Why don't you believe it is not a gas phase species ? What else could it be ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am limited to 500 characters. The gas storage is a 20 L stainless steel tank at 1500 PSI. The low pressure system is at 1 atm (14.6 PSI). I have a gas tank regulator (if you need to know what it looks like google CGA 660) attached between the gas tank and the low pressure flow system. Since the system is over pressurized relative to ambient air there will be no oxygen entering, and even if it were somehow entering, the rate constant for NO to NO2 by O2 is too slow for my residence time. I measure no O3 nor HO2, so those are not the sources. It has to be within the regulator.

Comment: There is a leak somewhere, because no mechanical device can transform NO into NO2, whatever its conception. Some source of oxygen is necessary somewhere.

Comment: You need an oxygen source for it to work. Exposure to oxygen oxidize NO to NO2 ($\ce{2NO + O2 -> 2NO2}$).